# What is this type of data with CENG prefix related to GEOLOCATION of a M2M SIM CARD?

Tags: geolocation, iot, sim

I'm troubleshooting an old proprietary software, and in the GEOLOCATION tab - which reports machines we have around the world - I found this piece of data for each machine:

[image: CENG]

So basically, for each machine I want to check, I get a data similar to this one above. I do not have the knowledge to interpret what is means.

Geolocation data is sent through a M2M SIM CARD installed in each machine.
I was expecting a COORDINATES info with a DATE/TIME attached to it. But this CENG information doesn't ring a bell for me.

What could it possibly mean? How should I interpret it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What could it possibly mean? How should I interpret it?

> The AT+CENG command is used to turn on the engineering (engg) mode to
> get detailed network information.
>
> The following info is available:
>
> 1. Frequency channel number,
> 2. Receive level,
> 3. Receive quality,
> 4. Mobile country code,
> 5. Mobile network code,
> 6. Base station identify code,
> 7. Cell id,
> 8. Location area code,
> 9. Receive level access minimum,
> 10. Transmit power maximum,
> 11. Timing advance.

Source: [AT+CENG – Switch on or off engineering mode | M2MSupport.net](https://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/atceng-switch-on-or-off-engineering-mode/)

Further Reading: [Tutorial for SIMCOM M2M Modules | M2MSupport.net](https://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/tutorial-for-simcom-m2m-modules/#Script)

Comment: Thank you very much!